# Invalid sso_key parameter iOS Gamemaker

Tags: ios, facebook, key, single-sign-on

When using Facebook implementation facebook says sso_key parameter invalid, the key com.mydomain.oldProvisioningProfile does not match any allowed allowed (repeated twice in actual error haha) bundle IDs. Configure your iOS bundle ID at link. I have the correct bundle ID in my app settings on facebook when I go to the link.

Is there anywhere else I have to change the bundle ID? What else could be going wrong?

Answer (score 10):

I know it's an old question, however... in xcode, you need to change the Bundle ID in the .plist file. It has to be the same as the one you used to register your app on Facebook. I fixed this and it worked for me.

Comment: It is worth noting that com.example.bundle is not the same as com.Example.Bundle. I don't think XCode minds the caps but Facebook needs the bundles to be identical

Answer (score 9):

The Bundle ID at the
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ must match with the Bundle identifier into the plist file in the Xcode project.See the picture for more detail:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by changed the **Bundle ID** field into the setting page on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/. I add the bundle ids with the same as into my plist file into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the problem is you need to build with a provisioning profile for that specific app and not the team ID.  I typically use the AdHoc type profile instead of development, but both should work.  But the provisioning profile for com.blah.blah.blah needs to match com.blah.blah.blah that you put on Facebook.  You can use any live iTunes connect app ID on Facebook until your app is really live.

Comment: there is not any option of com.blah.blah at my facebook.